# How can I use sed or ex to replace a block (multi-line code) with new block of text (code)?

Tags: sed, ex

I have to replace a large block of a text (shell script code) in a file with another block of text.

I am impressed with the [How can I use sed to replace a multi-line string?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26284/184145) answered by
[antak](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/21763/antak) and [Multi-line replace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/66115/184145) answered by [Bruce Ediger](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/732/bruce-ediger)

But I have some trouble in using them.

1. [antak](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/21763/antak) already mentioned in his answer that streaming entire file (`1h;2,$H;$!d;g;`) to the buffer is not advisable for large files, because it overload memory.
2. I know `sed` can be used with the block feature to preserve the text outside the block unchanged. I want to use this feature. But if I use,

   ```
   sed -i '/marker1/,/marker2/s/.*/new text (code)/' filename
   ```

it will insert new text (code) repeatedly for each stream. Hence I have to make the visual block as one stream, using something similar to what suggested by [antak](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/21763/antak) earlier, but for the block (not for entire file).

3. As mentioned by [Bruce Ediger](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/732/bruce-ediger) append feature of `ex` which begin with `a` end with `.`(dot) can be tried, but my new text (code) contain lines begin with dot, which may be considered as the dot of append syntax. How can I use it in this situation?
4. `ex`'s `dd` 'number of lines' may delete multiple lines, but if I have a block between /marker1/ and /marker2/ with the number of lines not fixed (varying) is to be replaced with new text (code), how to do it ?

Comment: I find your use of the term "visual block" unusual and confusing. Do you mean simply a block (group) of consecutive, complete lines?

Comment: Yes, I am editing the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: What is the source for the replacement text ? Is it in a file or is it "only in the programmers mind" ?

Comment: This is for situational patching of a shell script. Hence the source for the replacement text is the programmer's mind (Or a master script on which `sed` or `ex` command works).

Comment: [Don Crissti](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22142/don-crissti) I would have used `r` the read file command, to copy the text from another file, if source for the replacement text is in a file.

Comment: Please prepend the username with a `@`  (e.g. `@don_crissti`) otherwise we'll never know you replied (I just happened to have this open in a separate tab...) Yeah, that was the point of my question. You should still prefer `r` (write your text in a file and read it in) over the methods used below which do not mention the fact that some reserved characters may appear in the input and need escaping.

Answer (score 16):

I suggest using the **c**hange command
(which is essentially a **d**elete coupled with an **a**ppend, though the append is only applied for the last line in the range which is exactly what you want here):

```
sed -i '/marker1/,/marker2/c\
New text 1\
New text 2' filename
```

Here using GNU `sed`'s syntax for in-place editing (`-i`). That `c` command is otherwise standard and portable. GNU `sed` supports:

```
sed '/marker1/,/marker2/cNew text 1\
New text 2' filename
```

as a non-standard extension.

Newline and backslash characters must be escaped (with backslash) in the replacement text.

Comment: The change command works fine for both `sed` and `ex` alike. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid "\" and use here document for `sed` as in the case of `ex` syntax suggested by [Bruce Ediger](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/732/bruce-ediger) in [Multi-line replace](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/66115/184145).

Comment: You wouldn't need the backslashes if you use the `r` command discussed in other answers to that question.  I'm not sure how you would use a here document with `sed`.

Answer (score 9):

#### Using GNU sed

To replace lines starting a line matching `3` and continuing to a line matching `5` with `New Code`:

```
$ seq 8 | sed '/3/,/5/{/5/ s/.*/New Code/; t; d}'
1
2
New Code
6
7
8
```

For lines in the range `/3/,/5/`, we test to see if the line matches `5` (meaning that this is the last line in the group) and, if so, we do the substitution to insert `New Code`.  If the substitution was made, then the `t` command tells sed to jump to the end of the commands (in which case `New Code` is printed).  If not, the `d` command tells sed to delete the line.

All other lines are printed normally.

To change the file in place, the `-i` option can be used:

```
sed -i.bak '/3/,/5/{/5/ s/.*/New Code/; t; d}' file
```

#### Using awk

To do the same using awk:

```
$ seq 8 | awk '/3/,/5/{if (!f)print "New Code"; f=1; next}; 1'
1
2
New Code
6
7
8
```

The awk command treats lines in the range `/3/,/5/` specially.  For lines in that range, we test to see if `f` is zero (that is, if `!f` is true) and, if so, we print `New Code` and set `f` to 1 and then we skip the rest of the commands and jump to the `next` line.

For lines outside the range `/3/,/5/`, no jump is done and the `1` causes the line to be printed.  In more detail, `1` is a condition.  Because `1` is not zero, the condition evaluates to true.  Because no action is associated with the condition, the default action is performed which is to print the line.  Thus `1` is shorthand for print-the-line.

To change a file in place, the `-i inplace` option can be used with GNU `awk` 4.1 or above:

```
awk -i inplace '/3/,/5/{if (!f)print "New Code"; f=1; next} 1' file
```

Comment: cool. I am not good at `awk`, could you please explain bit your `awk` expression

Comment: @Rahul Sure.  I have added an explanation of the awk code.

Comment: Thanks [John](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/53604/john1024) This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Much simple to remove block then add new one to last line: `sed '/3/,/4/d;/5/cNew Code'` `awk '/5/{print "New Code"}/3/,/5/{next}1'`

Answer (score 2):

Based on the above discussion I come up with a solution using `ex`

```
seq 15 > test1.txt
ex test1.txt << EOEX
/^7/,/^9/c
abcd
123
.xyz
hfr4
.
w!
q
EOEX
cat test1.txt
```

The above gives

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
abcd
123
.xyz
hfr4
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

Thanks [g-man](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/80216/g-man) to make me aware of change command and give clarification about dot. Both `sed` and `ex` share almost similar syntax for the change command (also for delete command, append command, etc).