# How to use vim command-mode indention in ex colon-mode?

Tags: vim, ex

I am trying to script some file changes using `ex` per [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66167).

The issue that I'm running into is that `ex` seems to assume that every command is preceded by a colon, so while I can do something like:

```
/^foo()
a
test insertion
.
w!
q
```

I can't do:

```
/^foo()
>iB
O
if (bar())
.
w!
q
```

because it chokes on the second and third lines, as nearly as I can tell because `:>iB` and `:O` both return errors in `vim`.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I indent the current braces block and/or insert above the current line within `ex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `ex` seems to assume that every command is preceded by a colon […]

Actually, *you* are assuming that `vi` commands and `ex` commands are the same thing.  The character sequences that you type in full-screen mode to `vi` *are not* the command language of `ex`.

To insert above instead of append below, use `insert` instead of `append`.

To shift the current line left and right, use `>` and `<` on their own.  To shift a block, prefix them with a line range that specifies the block.

## Further reading

- Dale Dougherty and Tim O'Reilly (1987). "Advanced Editing". *[Unix Text Processing](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/utp/)*. Hayden Books.
- ["Utilities: ex"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html).  *Shell Command Language*.  Single UNIX Specification.  Issue 7.  IEEE 1003.1.  2016.  The Open Group.
- "[EX COMMANDS](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ex#EX_COMMANDS)".  *`ex`*.  *FreeBSD General Commands Manual*.  2013-11-02.
- [`:help cmdline-lines`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/cmdline.html#cmdline-lines) (NeoVIM)
- [`:help cmdline-lines`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#cmdline-lines) (VIM)
- `:exusage` (nvi)

Comment: Thank you.  The `append` was just what I needed, and the links are helpful.    
    
I have found the use of `>` to be inconsistent, though.  It works from the console, but when I try to pass in a series of commands (a la {{ex $FILENAME << END_EX_COMMANDS}}) it fails.  I can do `.>` and `+4>` but not `>` or `+.>>`.